# DataGridView to XDocument Exception Error using foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, linq-to-xml

I have the following code which correctly creates an xml document with the first record.  But only because I have included a break after I add the first record (line)

```
xdoc.Add(line);

break;
```

if I let the loop run (in order to add all the records) I get and Exception

Error:{"This operation would create an incorrectly structured document."}

Had a Search on here and found lots of examples but can't quite get me head around them and how they relate to what I am trying to do.

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();

                foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {


                    XElement line = new XElement("line");

                        XElement itemid = new XElement("field", dr.Cells["Item ID"].Value.ToString());

                            itemid.Add(new XAttribute("name", "item_id"));
                                line.Add(itemid);

                        XElement itemname = new XElement("field", dr.Cells["Item Name"].Value.ToString());

                            itemname.Add(new XAttribute("name", "item_name"));

                                line.Add(itemname);

                        XElement cost = new XElement("field", dr.Cells["Cost"].Value.ToString());

                            cost.Add(new XAttribute("name", "cost"));

                                line.Add(cost);

                    xdoc.Add(line);

                   break;

                 }

                   xdoc.Save(@"C:\xmltest\test3.xml");
```

It adds the first line when i break out why not the rest when I remove the break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well any XML document needs some root element so change `XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();` to e.g. `XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("root"));` and then add to the root, that is, change `xdoc.Add(line);` to `xdoc.Root.Add(line);`.